# auto refresh the div with dynamic data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a div section. I want to reload this section every 5 seconds. How do I do this. Here is my code:

```
<script>
    $("#send_parent_general_chat").submit(function() 
        {
            var rec = $("#data").val();
            var msg = $("#msg").val();
            var dataString = 'rec='+ rec + '&msg='+ msg;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "Client/send_general_parent_chat_msg/<?php echo $per_job->id;?>",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result){
                    $('#display_general_msg').html(result);
                    $('#send_parent_general_chat')[0].reset(); //form reset

                }
            });
            return false;
        }); 
</script>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(function(){
            //  alert("===111==");
            $("#display_general_msg").load('<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "Client/refresh_general_parent_chat_msg/<?php echo $per_job->id;?>')
        }, 5000);
    });
</script>
```

I have created one more controller for refreshing the div I have used the time interval function but it is not loading, it shows this error:

**Access forbidden!
You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.
If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 403**
I need to refresh only the div content not the whole page.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: I would recommend using websockets for this kind of application. It will safe your server and all users a ton of webtraffic.

Comment: As your tasks deal with short intervals, it can become CPU-intensive. I would suggest to use setTimeout instead of setInterval for this case

Comment: take a look http://reallifejs.com/brainchunks/repeated-events-timeout-or-interval/

Comment: First of all check whether  given url is opening normally or not by putting url in browser.

Comment: Using websockets will be the best approch as it has persistent connection to the server.

Comment: I think problem with your url concatenation part try this `$("#display_general_msg").load('<?php echo base_url(); ?>Client/refresh_general_parent_chat_msg/<?php echo $per_job->id;?>')`

Comment: Have you tried my above comment

Answer (score 5):

You can Use :

```
setTimeout(function()
{
  Your_Function(); //this will send request again and again;
}, 5000);
```

Replace `Your_Function` with your Function Name.

Hope this will help !!

Comment: @JYoThI no it is also possible to create a poll function for Repeated Events with setTimeout. In fact setTimeout is more convenient for CPU-intensive tasks and short intervals

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example which will update the contents in every 5 seconds using php websockets. This is a simple example, but you can use it to modify to fit for your application needs. You don't need the timeout functions on the client side here we use server `sleep`

Install the [Workerman socket library](https://github.com/walkor/Workerman)

```
composer require workerman/workerman
```

The client side code

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
   <head>

      <script type = "text/javascript">
         function WebSocketTest() {

            if ("WebSocket" in window) {
               //alert("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");

               // Let us open a web socket
               var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:2346");

               ws.onopen = function() {

                  // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
                  ws.send("Message to send");
                  //alert("Message is sent...");
               };

               ws.onmessage = function (evt) { 
                  var received_msg = evt.data;
                  //alert("Message is received..." + received_msg);
                  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Timestamp is updated every 5 sec " +received_msg;
               };

               ws.onclose = function() { 

                  // websocket is closed.
                  alert("Connection is closed..."); 
               };
            } else {

               // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
               alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
            }
         }

      </script>

   </head>

   <body>
      <div id = "sse">
         <a href = "javascript:WebSocketTest()">Run WebSocket</a>
      </div>
      <div id="demo" style="font-size: 64px; color: red;"></div>

   </body>
</html>
```

The Server side code

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Workerman\Worker;

// Create a Websocket server
$ws_worker = new Worker("websocket://0.0.0.0:2346");

// 4 processes
$ws_worker->count = 4;

// Emitted when new connection come
$ws_worker->onConnect = function($connection)
{
    echo "New connection\n";
 };

// Emitted when data received
$ws_worker->onMessage = function($connection, $data)
{
    // Send hello $data
    while(true) {
        $connection->send(time());
        sleep(5); //Sleep for 5 seconds to send another message.
    }

};

// Emitted when connection closed
$ws_worker->onClose = function($connection)
{
    echo "Connection closed\n";
};

// Run worker
Worker::runAll();
```

The backend service can be started with the following command from the terminal or you can autostart on boot if you want.

```
$php index.php start
```

Here `index.php` is our backendnd file name.

Just start the service and load the page then you can see the timestamp is updated every 5 seconds which comes from the server side. This is a working example tested on my local machine. Try and let me know if you need any other help.

> The output

[image: Updating content every 5 sex with websocket]

Answer (score 0):

you can also try below one:

```
setInterval(function(){
   loadlink() // this will run after every 5 seconds
}, 5000);
```

setInterval approach will be more accurate than the setTimeout approach

// or

```
  $(function(){  // document.ready function...
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('form').submit();
      },5000);
 });
```

Comment: i have tried like this  function reload_div() {
         $("#send_parent_general_chat").submit(function() {
              //data
            });}
             setTimeout(function(){
                 reload_div(); //this will send request again and again;
               }, 5000);
but it is not working

Comment: try this:

function reload_div() { 
$("#send_parent_general_chat").submit(function() { 
alert("") });
} 
setInterval(function(){
   reload_div();
}, 5000);

Comment: only once the alert is printing

Comment: remove return false in the end of form submit code.